# Finding the radius and the interval of convergence.

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I usually use Ratio Test to find the radius and the interval of convergence.
However, for this series, the ratio test does not work. If I use the ratio test, my answer is $|-2x+3|<1 $,  $-2<|x|<-1$

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x+3)^n}{\sqrt[3] n} $$

The radius and interval of conv for this series is $\frac{1}{2}, (1,2]$

I want to know why I can't use ratio test and which case do not have to use it.
Thank you.

Comment: Going from $|-2x+3|\lt 1$ to $-2\lt |x|\lt -1$ is wrong.  Go from the first inequality to $-1\lt -2x+3\lt 1$, then manipulate (separately) the two inequalities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can u tell me how to take $ a < |x| < b $ from $ |-2x+3|$ ?

Comment: No I cannot, because the correct inequality $|-2x+3|\lt 1$ is not equivalent to any inequality of the shape $a\lt |x|\lt b$.

Comment: It is however equivalent to $\left|x-\frac{3}{2}\right|\lt \frac{1}{2}$, but you are better off solving the two inequalities of my first comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Um.. If I do not use absolute value, I got $1<x<2$.
Is this okay I take out absolute sign?
Wow. dividing it by 2 is much better choice! :-)

Comment: Going from $|-2x+3|\lt 1$ to $-1\lt -2x+3\lt 1$ is indeed an absolutely legitimate step.  After we do that, the absolute value is gone, and we do familiar manipulations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay! :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of looks like the root test might be better:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{(-2x + 3)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-2x + 3}{n^{\frac{1}{3n}}}
\end{align}

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{\frac{1}{3n}}$ is indeterminate since it's, effectively, $\infty^0$...use L'Hospital's rule:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{3n}} =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{3n}}\\
=&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{3}} \\
=&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{1}{3n}} \\
=&\ e^0 \\
=&\ 1
\end{align}

Meaning that:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{(-2x + 3)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-2x + 3}{n^{\frac{1}{3n}}} \\
=&\ -2x + 3
\end{align}

Thus $|-2x + 3| < 1$:

$$
-2x + 3 < 1 \rightarrow x > 1 \\
-2x + 3 > -1 \rightarrow x < 2
$$

The interval of convergence is $1 < x < 2$...then you need to check $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ individually.  For $x = 1$ you have $-2 + 3 = 1$: $\frac{1^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ which clearly diverges by the p-series test.  Then you have, for $x = 2$, $-4 + 3 = -1$: $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ which clearly *converges* by the alternating series test.  Thus this series converges for:

$$
1 < x \leq 2
$$

Comment: I would argue that the ratio test is the best here. The power $a^n$ cancel nicely and the part $n^c$ has an easy to evaluate limit. I think root test is more suitable when you have exponential terms of the form $f(n)^n$...

Comment: @Jared Thank you your help! Um. How will you get the radius from your steps?

Comment: @bartgol Actually, I don't really see that one is necessarily better than the other here...perhaps the ratio test is a little easier since it gives: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-2x + 3)\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n + 1}} = -2x + 3$

Comment: That's my point. With ratio test you don't need to use L'Hopital. You just need to evaluate a limit of a rational function, which is really easy and fast.